# Why is $\sqrt{3}=[1;1,2,1,2,\dots]$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, continued-fractions

> Why is $\sqrt{3}=[1;1,2,1,2,\dots]$ ?

$\displaystyle[1;1,2,1,2,\dots]=1+\frac{1}{[1;2,1,2,\dots]}=1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{[1;2,1,2,\dots]}}}$

If I set $x=[1;2,1,2,\dots]$ then;

$\frac{x+1}{x}=\frac{5x+2}{3x+1}$

with solutions $x_{1,2}=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{3}}{2}$

what did go wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But then $\sqrt{3} = 1+1/x_1$. That's because $$\frac{1}{x_1}=\frac{2}{1+\sqrt 3} = \frac{2(\sqrt{3}-1)}{2} = \sqrt{3}-1$$

The other approach is to define:

$$y = 1+ \dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac1{1+y}}$$

Then you get $y=1+\frac{y+1}{y+2}=\frac{2y+3}{y+2}$ which reduces to $y^2=3$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's begin by computing $y=[1;2,1,2,\cdots]$.  This is $$1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2+\ddots}}}.$$

Now, $\frac{1}{y-1}$ equals $$2+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2+\ddots}}.$$

Then, $$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{y-1}-2}=y.$$

Simplifying the fractions results in $2y^2-2y-1$.  Solving for $y$ results in $\frac{1\pm\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Since $x=1+\frac{1}{y}$, you get that $x=\pm\sqrt{3}$.